# Why can not write registry from application what started automatically from HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

Tags: vb.net, windows, registry, uac

My VB.NET program automatically start from registry

**`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`**

But when it try to write a registry key this error occured:

`System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyCorporation\MyApplication is denied.`

Comment: It may be a UAC problem or because of limited access of user account or an anti-virus problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because writing to HKLM requires, in general, admin access, and your app runs as a non-privileged user. Modify your app to use [HKCU](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976337.aspx) instead. Alternatively you can add a manifest to require elevated privileges.

You should consider creating a service instead of an application that runs on start.